# A more efficient/cleaner way of scrolling a div's contents in HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

My current code for scrolling an image contained within a div is:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scroll {
      position: absolute;
      white-space: nowrap;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    #oScroll {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 128px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll(oid, iid) {
      this.oCont = document.getElementById(oid)
      this.ele = document.getElementById(iid)
      this.width = this.ele.clientWidth;
      this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth;
      this.move = function() {
        this.ele.style.left = this.n + "px"
        this.n--
          if (this.n < (-this.width)) {
            this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth
          }
      }
    }
    var vScroll

    function setup() {
      vScroll = new scroll("oScroll", "scroll");
      setInterval("vScroll.move()", 20)
    }
    onload = function() {
      setup()
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oScroll">
    <img id="scroll" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8i8o.png' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This was designed some time ago, and I was thinking that there must be a better way of writing it now.

Since my project requires performance over looks, I want to have a **high performing** page, but still with little animations like this.

Is there a more efficient way of creating something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed! You can move your entire animation into CSS:

```
#car-container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#car-container > div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8i8o.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    animation: moveCar 10s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: moveCar 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    moveCar 10s linear infinite;      
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveCar {
    0% { left: 200px; }
    100% { left: -200px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveCar {
    0% { left: 200px; }
    100% { left: -200px; }
}
@keyframes moveCar {
    0% { left: 200px; }
    100% { left: -200px; }
}
```

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/3676/

Comment: I love css! (even though i'm not very good t it lol). So thank you for this, will defo look into using this type of desin more often! cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of recommendations on the JS side if you choose not to use the CSS-only solution:

- Use private vars with the `var` statement instead of instance vars
  with the `this` statement unless you need to actually expose this
  properties for public inspection or use by another object.
- Don't make vScroll into a global - it is only used in the scope of `setup` so it can be defined inside of setup, and if it isn't global, you can pass vScroll.move by reference to setInterval instead of using setInterval's quote syntax, which [requires an extra parsing step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801700/802397).
- Use a cross-browser compatible document.ready like [jQuery's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283456/802397), or in the very least use DOMContentLoaded. The onload event can wait for the [entire document to load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414766/802397), including CSS, but DOMContentLoaded occurs when the DOM is available (will increase load speed).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #scroll {
      position: absolute;
      white-space: nowrap;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    #oScroll {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 128px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function scroll(oid, iid) {
  // 1. These should all be private vars instead of instance vars
  var oCont = document.getElementById(oid),
      ele = document.getElementById(iid),
      width = ele.clientWidth,
      n = oCont.clientWidth;

  // Public API, used by another object (app)
  this.move = function() {
    // Missing semi-colons
    ele.style.left = n + "px";
    n--;
    if (n < -width) {
      n = oCont.clientWidth;
    }
  }
}

// 2. No need for vScroll in this scope unles you need it outside of the setup function
// var vScroll

function setup() {
  var vScroll = new scroll("oScroll", "scroll");
  // 3. Pass a reference to setInterval instead of global var in quotes
  setInterval(vScroll.move, 20)
}

// 4. Use DOMContentLoaded as document.ready instead of window.onload
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  setup()
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oScroll">
    <img id="scroll" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8i8o.png' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```